# Is there an ecart/ecommerce plugin that integrates directly in to existing pages and can be visually customised?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, e-commerce

I am wondering if anyone out there knows of an e-cart/e-commerce plugin that bolts directly on to existing pages, allows shipping costs & discount codes, and obviously accepts Paypal payments.

The reason I want it to integrate with existing pages is because I am running a custom built theme. I looked at wp e-commerce but I couldn't work out how to integrate my theme styling in to the plugin (I don't know anything about hooks and my knowledge of php is pretty much none existent). Hence looking for something that can be added straight on to existing pages and posts. I also have my product pages pre-built and use a custom gallery to view the products so just a simple add to cart button is needed.

I thought I had hit the jackpot with eshop which would have been perfect, but it turns out the look is not fully customisable. Below the page content it adds an Add to Cart panel with a 1px grey border, title and description all of which can't be removed. It also can't be relocated and has to stay underneath the page content.

Here is a sample page so you can see what i mean [Sample Page](http://bit.ly/Xoq20B)

All I want on my product page is nothing more than an add to cart button (using a custom image) added to a location of my choosing (bottom right of big image below thumbnails, its bottom inline with the bottom of main image), and maybe (but not essential) a quantity input field above the add to card button.

The plugin needs to include shipping costs and discount codes.

Is this possible, does anyone know of a plugins out there that provide this?

Any help would be much appreciated as I am really struggling to complete this site.

Comment: Don't be surprised if this gets voted down. It's not code-related, it begs for subjective answers and/or discussion, and you could find the information you're looking for with some steadfast Google searching.

Comment: Probably right. I have just found what I am looking for, though it has taken me days. Thanks for the warning though. Will remove it now.

Answer (score 0):

It has taken me days but I have found a very good plugin.

"WordPress Ultra Simple Paypal Shopping Cart"

Thanks anyway people. Can't wait until my php is up to the standard when I can create my own.